# How to collapse cell borders in ssrs

Tags: ssrs, ssrs-2008-r2

I have been creating some reports in SSRS 2008 R2. When I need to make borders that show up for all rows, both on the top and bottom of the report, as well as all the rows in between I can tell that the inner borders of the report are thicker because it is actually 2 borders side by side.

Is there a way to collapse borders that are side by side?

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know how to do this is to remove either the left-hand or right-hand border from the cells where it is double. A very laborious work-around and something that should be addressed as a bug.